# Fastest way to slice a numpy 1d array based on consecutive True values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` 1d array like this:

```
a = np.array([False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False])
```

I want to find the index of the first `True` value in the array (`1` in this case) and the last index of the first consecutive `True` sequence (`3` in this case).

I actually can imagine a lot of solutions for this problem, but I'm looking for the cleanest way to solve this task. For simplicity assume that there is almost one `True` in the array

some other examples could be useful (expected output as `#comment`):

```
[False, True, True] # 1, 2
[True, True, True, False, True, True, False] # 0, 2
[False, True, True, True] # 1, 3
[False, True, False, True] # 1, 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My method would be:

1. use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find indexes of all True values
2. add +1 and use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) to find the first False after the first True
3. return the first idx found in step (1), and the predecessor of the idx found in step (2).

```py
def slice_true_values(a):
    w = np.where(a)[0]
    d = np.setdiff1d(w + 1, w)
    return w[0], d[0] - 1
```

Trying to explain the logic:
when we add +1 to each index of the `where` array, all consecutive indexes will be present in both the original and the +1 array, except for the last one.

Comment: is `np.where` the fastest? it looks for all occurrences instead of stopping at the first match.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki If there's a faster way to find the index of the 1st occurrence we could definitely use it for a faster (and simpler) solution. I didn't find any which wasnt `np.where(...)[0][0]`

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Didn't know the `setdiff1d` method.